# How to make complete-callout function correctly?

Tags: javascript, payment-gateway

I'm making CIB payment gateway , and I want to execute a function if payment is success ,

I've put that attribute in the checkout link

```
data-complete="completeCallback"
```

and made a function

```
function completeCallback() {
  console.log('Payment Done');
}
```

but I get error

Callback defined by 'data-complete' not allowed without 'session.id'

I don't really relate where should I get the session.id  ?

That is documention

https://cibpaynow.gateway.mastercard.com/api/documentation/apiDocumentation/checkout/version/latest/callback/complete.html?locale=en_US

and here is how to work with sessions

https://cibpaynow.gateway.mastercard.com/api/documentation/apiDocumentation/nvp/version/latest/operation/Session%3a%20Create%20Session.html?locale=en_US

if anyone can help

Answer (score 0):

Your completeCallback function should match the data-complete signature, according to the documentation it should be:

```
function completeCallback(resultIndicator, sessionVersion) {
         //handle payment completion
}
```

Not parameter-less function!